# how to write a read DICOM file using VTK or ITK libraries?

Tags: image-processing, processing, vtk, dicom, itk

I used vtkDICOMImageReader to read the DICOM file. I used the vtkImageThreshold to threshold a CT image. And now i want to write it back to my hard disk before further processing.

I tried vtkImageWriter library to write it back. But it is not working when i try to open the file using 3D slicer. I am much grateful if anyone can suggest me a methodology for writing Dicom files.

i have included my code here and i am trying to threshold a dicom image and viewing it. Then i would like to save the thresholded image as a dicom file. But i could not succeed in doing that. please help me.

thanks in advance.

```
#include <itkImageToVTKImageFilter.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>
#include <vtkImageData.h>
#include <vtkImageThreshold.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindow.h>
#include <vtkRenderWindowInteractor.h>
#include <vtkInteractorStyleImage.h>
#include <vtkRenderer.h>
#include <vtkImageMapper3D.h>
#include <vtkImageActor.h>
#include <vtkImageCast.h>
#include <vtkNIFTIImageWriter.h>
#include <vtkImageMandelbrotSource.h>
#include <vtkImageViewer2.h>
#include <vtkDICOMImageReader.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

std::string folder = argv[1];

vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader> reader =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader>::New();
reader->SetFileName(folder.c_str());
reader->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2> imageViewer =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageViewer2>::New();
imageViewer->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());

// threshold the images
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageThreshold> imageThreshold = 
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageThreshold>::New();
imageThreshold->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
// unsigned char lower = 127;
unsigned char upper = 511;

imageThreshold->ThresholdByLower(upper);
imageThreshold->ReplaceInOn();
imageThreshold->SetInValue(0);
imageThreshold->ReplaceOutOn();
imageThreshold->SetOutValue(511);
imageThreshold->Update();

// Create actors
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> inputActor =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor>::New();
inputActor->GetMapper()->SetInputConnection(
  reader->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> thresholdedActor =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor>::New();
thresholdedActor->GetMapper()->SetInputConnection(
imageThreshold->GetOutputPort());

// There will be one render window
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
renderWindow->SetSize(600, 300);

// And one interactor
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> interactor =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
interactor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

// Define viewport ranges
// (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
double leftViewport[4] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0};
double rightViewport[4] = {0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};

// Setup both renderers
vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> leftRenderer =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(leftRenderer);
leftRenderer->SetViewport(leftViewport);
leftRenderer->SetBackground(.6, .5, .4);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> rightRenderer =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(rightRenderer);
rightRenderer->SetViewport(rightViewport);
rightRenderer->SetBackground(.4, .5, .6);

leftRenderer->AddActor(inputActor);
rightRenderer->AddActor(thresholdedActor);

leftRenderer->ResetCamera();
rightRenderer->ResetCamera();

renderWindow->Render();
interactor->Start();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkNIFTIImageWriter> writer =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkNIFTIImageWriter>::New();
writer->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
writer->SetFileName("output");
writer->Write();

// writing the thresholded image to the hard drive.
//this is the part i am not able to code. Please can somebody help me     please? 

return EXIT_SUCCESS;

 }
```

Comment: You'll have to show your code for anyone to be able to help

Comment: thanks for commenting. can you please check the code and tell me how to savw the thresholded image in dicom format?

Answer (score 0):

First, do you want to save out the thresholded image or just the image as read in? If not replace reader with imageThreshold

```
writer->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort())
```

From looking at the VTK tests of NIFTI readers and writers the following options may be required...

```
writer->SetNIFTIHeader(reader->GetNIFTIHeader())
writer->SetQFac(reader->GetQFac());
writer->SetTimeDimension(reader->GetTimeDimension());
writer->SetTimeSpacing(reader->GetTimeSpacing());
writer->SetRescaleSlope(reader->GetRescaleSlope());
writer->SetRescaleIntercept(reader->GetRescaleIntercept());
writer->SetQFormMatrix(reader->GetQFormMatrix());
```

I would test with adding these options and then see what you get

Answer (score 0):

I think VTK is a little bit confused to process image. I only use it to display image.I wrote a piece of code for you. The code which read , threshold and write dicom image is below.It use only itk. I think it fills the bill.

```
    #include "itkBinaryThresholdImageFilter.h"
    #include "itkImageFileReader.h"
    #include "itkGDCMImageIO.h"
    #include "itkImageFileWriter.h"
    #include "itkImage.h"

    int main () {
    typedef unsigned char InputPixelType ;  //Pixel Type of Input image
    typedef unsigned char OutputPixelType;  //Pixel Type of Output image
    const unsigned int InputDimension = 2;  //Dimension of image

    typedef itk::Image < InputPixelType, InputDimension > InputImageType; //Type definition of Input Image
    typedef itk::Image < InputPixelType, InputDimension > OutputImageType;//Type definition of Output Image
    typedef itk::ImageSeriesReader< InputImageType > ReaderType;//Type definition of Reader  
    typedef itk::BinaryThresholdImageFilter<InputImageType, OutputImageType > FilterType; // Type definition of Filter
    typedef itk::ImageFileWriter<OutputImageType> ImageWriterType; //Definition of Writer of Ouput image
    typedef itk::GDCMImageIO ImageIOType; //Type definition of Image IO for Dicom images

//Starts Reading Process
    ReaderType::Pointer reader = ReaderType::New(); //Creates reader
    ImageIOType::Pointer gdcmImageIO_input = ImageIOType::New(); //Creates ImageIO object for input image

    reader->SetImageIO( gdcmImageIO_input ); // Sets image IO of reader
    reader->SetFileNames( "example_image.dcm" ); // Sets filename to reader

//Exceptional handling
    try
    {
          reader->UpdateLargestPossibleRegion();
    }
    catch (itk::ExceptionObject & e)
    {
          std::cerr << "exception in file reader " << std::endl;
          std::cerr << e << std::endl;
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
// Start filtering process
    FilterType::Pointer filter = FilterType::New(); //Creates filter
    filter->SetInput( reader->GetOutput() );
    filter->SetOutsideValue( 0);  // Set pixel value which are out of lower and upper threshold value
    filter->SetInsideValue( 255 );// Set pixel value which are within lower and upper threshold value
    filter->SetLowerThreshold( 25 ); // Lower threshold value 25
    filter->SetUpperThreshold( 150 );// Upper threshold value 150
    filter->Update();


//Starts Writing Process

    ImageWriterType::Pointer imageWriter = ImageWriterType::New(); // Creates writer
    ImageIOType::Pointer gdcmImageIO_output = ImageIOType::New(); // Creates Image IO object for output image

    imageWriter->SetImageIO( gdcmImageIO_output ); // Set image IO as dicom
    imageWriter->SetInput(filter->GetOutput() );  // Connects output of filter with to input of writer
    imageWriter->SetFileName(example_image_thresholded.dcm); // Sets output file name
//Exceptional handling
    try
      {
      imageWriter->Update();
      }
    catch ( itk::ExceptionObject &exception )
      {
      std::cerr << "Exception in file writer ! " << std::endl;
      std::cerr << exception << std::endl;

      return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much  for your time sir.

I tried ITK threshold filter before too. but was not successful in making a threshold filter for binary pixel values which range from 0 to 511. when i use the above piece of code i get a really blurry one and features of the dicom image is not clear as well. I think this filter can only be used for images of range 0-255.  But that range is not suitable for my task. 

i want to extract bony areas of a skull. So i want to extract pixels of value in between 500-511. this method does not allow me to do that. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually I don't  agree with you.Did you try the change lower-upper threshold values and outside-inside values for your situation.I think it should work in all pixel range succesfully.Even if it is not work, you can write basicly for loops and change each pixel one by one if you want.

Comment: To give some extra advice, you shouldn't try to strip skull directly.If you take a look on literature you'll see many pre-processing step such as median filtering.Also, you will see that thresholding is not useful method to strip skull from image.For mri images there is a tool to extract skull area of brain.You may want to examine it.you can find more info about it on [link](https://github.com/cactuxx/skullStrip) .In CT images, skull is a little bit more obvious than in mri images ,but ,even so, you may lost little amount of data which out of skull.

Comment: Finally if you can upload any one of your images on the internet, I can try binary threshold filter on it.
Actually I just realized now that  you used nifti image writer to write image. Why don't you use dicomImagewriter class instead of nifti ? Is there any special reason ? If the answer no, could you try to use dicomwriter ?

Comment: I am sorry if i am making you confused. I am very beginner for ITK and VTK libraries. Yes i tried to use different ranges but the output is not satisfactory. I managed to do it using VTK libraries and i will send you the results and the original files as well. What i got from itk is a file like half the size of the original one. But using vtk i managed to take the same size file which was quite clear and satisfactory. I will upload dicom results and script as well.

Comment: no i didnt use the nifti writer though i have said so in here. Later i changed it and now using general writer and i copy the header from the original to the new file. That way i can make the file a dicom one.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6YWOy7hR4VGMW96eTkyUjR6STA&usp=sharing

this includes an original dicom file, result i took using vtk libraries and itk code and the piece of code i used.